# How to pass scope parameter and object for function call in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="editForm.quantity{{product.productId}}.$invalid" ng-click="addProduct(product);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>&nbsp;<span translate="global.form.addToCart"> Add to cart</span>
                      </button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addProduct = function (ViewProduct)
{
  CatalogAdd.addProductToCart(ViewProduct);
};
```

Service:

```
angular.module('brotzeitApp')
.factory('CatalogAdd', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
    return $resource('api/_add/catalog', {}, {
        'addProductToCart': { method:'GET'}
    });
});
```

Java Function:

```
public ResponseEntity<Cart> addProductToCart(final ViewProduct aProduct) throws URISyntaxException
```

All of this works an intended. Complete object is passed from html/js to the java funtion and i can save.
Now i want to add another parameter to the function.
I tried the following.

Controller:

```
$scope.addProduct = function (ViewProduct)
{
  CatalogAdd.addProductToCart({orgid: $rootScope.orgid}, ViewProduct);
};
```

Service:

```
angular.module('brotzeitApp')
.factory('CatalogAdd', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
    return $resource('api/_add/catalog', {}, {
        'addProductToCart': { method:'GET', params:{orgid:$rootScope.orgid}}
    });
});
```

Java:

```
public ResponseEntity<Cart> addProductToCart(@RequestParam(value = "orgid" , required = true) final Long orgid,
final ViewProduct aProduct) throws URISyntaxException
```

And now only the "orgid" parameter is passed to the java funtion but not the ViewProduct. I tried several ways to define and pass both, the orgid and the ViewProduct object, but no success. Any hint on how to define the methods/parameters that both are passed to my java funtion?

Comment: The last service call only contains params:{orgid:$rootScope.orgid} which will only pass orgid in method. You need to modify it with params:{orgid:$rootScope.orgid, product: ViewProduct}

Comment: But the service wont know the ViewProduct here and in the first step the ViewProduct is not listed in the service params, but passed to the java funtion. So just adding the ViewProduct to the service params does not work, even if passed to the service via the rootScope and defined as RequestParameter for the java funtion.